# Query not working properly for trunc

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
Select TRUNCATE(convert('2.3' using utf8) ,5) from dual;
```

Comment: Does MariaDB have `dual`? That's more of an Oracle thing.

Comment: Apparently it does: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dual/

Comment: What is the `convert using utf8` part supposed to do?

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the result that you get? How does it differ from the behavior that you would expect?

Comment: This is just a line of code, not a question. Why is it not working, do you get an error, if so what is the error, do you get wrong results, if so what is your data/actual output/expected output? I don't have a crystal ball which allows me to look at your data, I need **you** to give me the information needed to solve **your** problem!